# How to run google chrome headless in docker?

Tags: google-chrome, docker, jenkins, e2e-testing

My problem is how to run google chrome in docker container for e2e testing.
I create a `Dockerfile` from official Jenkins image, but when try to run google chrome, it crashes and show the error:

```
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

The Jenkins docker image uses Debian `jessie`.

I can run google chrome with `--headless` flag and the X server is not needed.

This is my docker file:

- https://github.com/ripper2hl/jenkinswithchrome

Jenkins official image:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

The repo a person runs google chrome with GUI from docker:

- https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/blob/master/chrome/stable/Dockerfile

My first approach is to use `xvbf`, but the process is more simple when used `--headless` flag.

- https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747

I can run chrome in Ubuntu server with the same commands for installation, but in docker it fails.

After other intents, I used `--no-sandbox` flag, but docker images shows the next error.

```
[0427/180929.595479:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[0427/180929.595537:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted
```

Actually I ran this command:

`google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox http://www.google.com`

Comment: Would love to have this, especially now that `google-chrome-beta` (version 59) is out. I've tried getting it up and running and hit the same issues.

Comment: Have you tried to run it with all these flags? google-chrome-unstable --disable-gpu --headless --user-data-dir=/var/jenkins_home/chrome-data

Comment: This is how i run a C# app + Selenium in Docker: [Other question, same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67912538/8529170)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using this image `alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk` worked for me in ubuntu!
The command used in that container to launch headless chrome is this:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-unstable \
--disable-gpu --headless --no-sandbox \
--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 \
--remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=/data
```

here's a short video of the container in action
[image: chrome headless in action]

I launched the container in Ubuntu with this command:

```
 docker run -it --rm -p=0.0.0.0:9222:9222 \ 
 --name=chrome-headless \
 -v /tmp/chromedata/:/data alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk
```

then used Chrome to connect to the debug port at `localhost:9222`

With some modifications you could probably get this running in **Jenkins**!

### Sources

- https://hub.docker.com/r/alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk/
- https://github.com/alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk

Comment: Whats the reason you are adding `--disable-gpu`?

Comment: --no-sandbox = huge security problem

Comment: @Merc yes, it is a known security issue. Do you have an example that you can share that does not use --no-sandbox?

Comment: GitHub repo is stale since Aug 14, 2021

Answer (score 12):

Just launch chrome with `--no-sandbox` that s resolves the problem

Comment: This can be a serious security issue. This [simple post](https://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/big_26.html) explains why. [This second one explains why in details](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md)

Comment: Instead of `--no-sandbox`, you may be able to just use a custom `seccomp`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975412/970288).

Comment: Just out of curiosity @CyrilN. ... if you are running Chrome inside a Docker instance, which is a sort of sandbox, wouldn't that make the `--no-sandbox` parameter useless?

Comment: @JwJosefy Maybe, I'm not a Docker specialist. I think it would depends on what other things you run on your Docker instance. If it's just Chrome, then I'd go with yes, but with a grain of salt.

Comment: That second article does NOT explain why this is a security issue, instead it just explains what the sandbox is and what it's purpose is. There is not enough context to imply this is fundamentally insecure.

Answer (score 4):

This article is exactly what I needed to run Karma tests with Headless Chrome inside docker:

https://hackernoon.com/running-karma-tests-with-headless-chrome-inside-docker-ae4aceb06ed3

Basically, the solution is to run Headless Chrome with the `--no-sandbox` flag.

Comment: This has already been said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846909)

Comment: ... and it's a [huge security issue.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68832/what-does-the-chromium-option-no-sandbox-mean)

Answer (score 3):

We built a Docker image with Chrome and Chromedriver that runs Chrome in headless mode for automated tests. We're using this as a drop-in replacement for PhantomJS in our `docker-compose.yml` setups. The image is based on Alpine Linux and doesn't need or include Selenium so it's pretty small.

Source:
https://github.com/retreatguru/headless-chromedriver

Docker Hub:
https://hub.docker.com/r/retreatguru/headless-chromedriver

Comment: GitHub repo is stale since on Jan 22, 2018

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the answer but I know a container which successfully launch a headless Chrome in Docker. The selenium one:

[Selenium Chrome Node](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/~/dockerfile/)

I use it for automated testing of my webapp in Chrome

Hope it helps

Comment: which testing library do u use? I tried setting up `mocha` with `webdriver.io`  but i always end up with `Error: A session id is required for this command but wasn't found in the response payload` when trying to get a value from the browser

Answer (score 1):

I extend default Dockerfile [Selenium Chrome Node](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/~/dockerfile/) by following

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:latest
MAINTAINER Serge Arbuzov <Serge.Arbuzov@advantechwireless.com>

USER root

### jenkins set up ###
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server sudo
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN adduser jenkins
RUN echo jenkins:jenkins | chpasswd
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL">>/etc/sudoers

USER root
RUN echo export DISPLAY=":1.5" >> /etc/environment
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

And my run.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

So i can use default image as Jenkins node