# Selenium chrome crashes in jenkins slave

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker, jenkins, headless

Im trying to run UI tests using selenium in headless mode. I see the chrome is browser is crashing whenever i try to load the driver. Here are the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/behave/model.py", line 1456, in run
          match.run(runner.context)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/behave/model.py", line 1903, in run
          self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
        File "steps/collectorUi.py", line 35, in step_impl
          assert context.ndpUt.driverInit(title="Pegasus Portal") is not False, 'Initial page title didnt match'
        File "../collectorSanity/libs/ndpUi.py", line 91, in driverInit
          browser=self.browser)
        File "../runner/testutils/seleniumutils.py", line 70, in __init__
          executable_path=self.browserPath+self.browserDriver)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
          desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
          self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
          response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
          self.error_handler.check_response(response)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
          raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
      selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.2.0-16-generic x86_64)
```

I have installed xvfb and google-chrome on ubuntu. The following are environment variables I tried to set before running the tests.

Env:

```
export DISPLAY=:10
nohup sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1900x980x24 &
```

When i run in docker container, Im get the following errors.

```
jenkins@26cccde068c0:~/e2e$ nohup sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1900x980x24 &
_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 10
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X10-lock
    and start again.
(EE)
```

In the selenium library, the following are display and parameters of chrome driver.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumUi(object):
     def __init__(self, ....):

         if isHeadless:
            self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1900, 980))
            self.display.start()
        # secure
        if secure:
            self.webpage = 'https://{}{}'.format(self.hostname, webpageUri)
        else:
            self.webpage = 'http://{}{}'.format(self.hostname, webpageUri)
        # firefox options
        if self.browser.lower() == 'firefox':
            if ignoreCert:
                # ignoring the certs
                self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
                self.profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.profile)
            else:
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        # chrome options
        elif self.browser.lower() == 'chrome':
            #os.system('killall -9 chromedriver')
            self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            self.options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
            #self.options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") # don't delete this
            self.options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
            self.options.add_argument('--window-size=1400,900')
            #self.options.add_argument('--allow-file-access-from-files')
            #self.options.add_argument('--allow-file-access')
            #self.options.add_argument('--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt')
            #self.options.add_argument('--allow-control-allow-origin')
            #self.options.add_argument('--allow-control-allow-methods')
            #self.options.add_argument('--allow-control-allow-headers')
            #self.options.add_argument('--disable-default-apps')
            if ignoreCert:
                # ignoring the certs
                self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            log.debug('browserPath:{} browserDriver:{}'.format(self.browserPath, self.browserDriver))
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.options,
                                           executable_path=self.browserPath+self.browserDriver)
```

Kindly let me know what could be the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggesting using docker/selenium, will make yoir life easier if you already using docker. I've done this path. For the error, it looks like display 10 already used, you could check it with ps aux | grep Xvfb

Comment: While running UI tests in docker, you need to run the docker container with the following options.   docker run -it --security-opt seccomp:unconfined <container name> ... it disables the security. After doing that the google chrome started working with xvfb running the background.

Comment: [Maybe this answer will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665276/how-to-run-google-chrome-headless-in-docker/43675986#43675986)