# ChromeDriver Version that works with Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81 while using selenium with Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had built a web-scraper with an old version of chrome and it was working well and then chrome autoupdated itself with version 69.0.3497.81 and now any website doesn't seem to recognise the web browser while scraping. Is there a version if ChromeDriver that works well? I also tried downgrading chrome to previous versions, but doesn't seem to work anymore

(Note:- I tried ChromeDriver 2.41 and it doesn't work right.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you changed Chrome path while upgrading it?

Comment: Are you using serverless-chrome (https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases)?  That's what arrived me here, because its latest release (3 days before this question posted) does not have any versions that Google still publishes a compatible (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection) ChromeDriver with (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the *ChromeDriver* Version that works in sync with the respective *Chrome Browser* Version you can adopt the following strategy:

- Keep *Auto Update* of *Chrome Browser* **`OFF`**
- Identify your current *Chrome Browser* version.
- As per the [*Release Notes* of *ChromeDriver*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) download the respective *ChromeDriver* version from [**ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)

As per *best practices*:

- Keep your *Test Environment* always updated with the latest *ChromeDriver*.
- Always keep the *Chrome Browser* updated to the latest GA release.

**Note** : Each version of *ChromeDriver* is released considering the support of the:

- Latest *Released GA* version of *Chrome Browser*
- Previous version of *Chrome Browser*
- Next version of *Chrome Browser*

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Specific version of a *ChromeDriver* binary supports a specific range of *Chrome Browser* versions as below:

- *ChromeDriver v**2.41** (2018-07-27)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v67-69
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.40** (2018-06-07)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v66-68
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.39** (2018-05-30)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v66-68
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.38** (2018-04-17)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v65-67
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.37** (2018-03-16)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v64-66
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.36** (2018-03-02)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v63-65
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.35** (2018-01-10)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v62-64
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.34** (2017-12-10)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v61-63
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.33** (2017-10-03)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v60-62
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.32** (2017-08-30)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v59-61
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.31** (2017-07-21)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v58-60
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.30** (2017-06-07)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v58-60
  ```
- *ChromeDriver v**2.29** (2017-04-04)*

  ```
  Supports Chrome v56-58
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add you google account in the emulator and update google chrome from playstore to work it for latest chrome driver.