# Protractor latest Chrome tests no longer running

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, e2e-testing

Until a few weeks ago I had my Protractor e2e tests working with the Chrome browser. 
However, since the last Chrome update 69.0.3497.100 (64-bit) running the tests in non-headless mode don't work any more and I get an error. If i run the tests in headless mode (via `chromeOptions` in the protractor config file "--headless") all works fine.

The error i get in the windows command prompt is:

> WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
>     (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737......)

Chrome is always closed before I run the e2e tests.

I have done a webdriver-manager clean and after, a webdriver-manager update.
I also manually installed chromedriver@latest via npm but still no luck.

My chromeOptions in the config file is

```
chromeOptions: {
args: ["--user-data-dir", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", '--disable-web-security']
    },
```

On running the e2e tests, chrome launches properly, but the tab remains on the default new tab page. If in the config, I tel it to use FF, the pages change properly.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: i've been through [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221) still no luck.

Comment: After webdriver-manager update i now get: 
The error I get after update is: 
Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified.
Many:
ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(192)] Cache is not initialized, cannot RetrieveEntry.
then:
E/launcher - unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 trimmed)
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Comment: I 'fixed' the Registry error as found a few posts mentioning that error, but still page don't change in the chrome browser and the tests wont run.                                    
I now get multpile error lines with the following:                                                    
 ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(192)] Cache is not initialized, cannot RetrieveEntry.                                                                                                    
 And at the very end I get: DNS config watch failed.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot get rid of this

```
<rejected> { WebDriverError: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
[protractor] from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
[protractor] from tab crashed
[protractor]   (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
[protractor]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

tried with `chromedriver=2.42` too.

Workaround is moving to `chrome32_68.0.3440.84` and disable 
Google Update Service (gupdatem) and 
Google Update Service (gupdate) windows services (if you are on windows) to stop chrome automatic update.