# Error: System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73 using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, visual-studio-2015, selenium-chromedriver

```
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at WhitelabelUITest_New.Initializers.Initialize() in X:\QA\WhitelabelUI-Automation\WhitelabelUITest-New\Initializers.cs:line 87
   at WhitelabelUITest_New.Initializers..ctor() in X:\QA\WhitelabelUI-Automation\WhitelabelUITest-New\Initializers.cs:line 41
   at WhitelabelUITest_New.Webpage..ctor()
   at WhitelabelUITest_New.ImpressionTests..ctor()
Result Message: Unable to create instance of class WhitelabelUITest_New.ImpressionTests. Error: System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated).
```

I installed the latest version of Chrome driver, but every time I run a test case, it does not initiate the Chrome driver and the test fails.

Comment: Update your chrome browser version to 73

Comment: So... did you check if your Chrome version is between 70 and 73?

Comment: Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68. that might be above 73; this code might literally mean "no newer that 73.0.0"

Comment: I mentioned it already that the driver is updated to 73.0.3683.68. But this issue is only on My PC. my college is using the same project on his PC and it worked fine. Only when i am trying to run the test case on my PC from source control, it fails

Comment: @Analyst It's about BROWSER version, not the DRIVER

Comment: Yes, It is chromedriver version. Right now as a temporary solution i switched to firefox and i am able to start working but i need to resolve it in able to start using chromedriver.

Comment: How do you launch browser - Using WebDriverManager or setting binary manually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error message...

```
Result Message: Unable to create instance of class WhitelabelUITest_New.ImpressionTests. Error: System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated).
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* expects the *Chrome Browser* version to be **between 70 and 73**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=73.0.3683.68*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=73.0.3683.68*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v73**

- Your *Chrome Browser* version is unknown to us.

It is pretty evident your *Chrome Browser* version is not of version **73.0**

---

### Solution

- Keep *ChromeDriver* to [**ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade/Downgrade *Chrome* version to ***Chrome v73*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: Thanks Debanjan. I noticed my chrome version is still 69.0.3497.92 which is not compatible.Thanks for your help. i totally missed checking the version earlier.

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall Chrome
2. Install it again from the offline installer [here](https://www.neowin.net/news/google-chrome-730368386-offline-installer).