# How to fix this issue " chrome browser compatibilty issue in selenium webdriver"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just trying to automate a piece of code for automating the contact form, it was working fine a month ago but right now it's showing the below mention error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.19 seconds
```

version compatibility issue, my chrome version is 74.** something and selenium is supporting 70-73

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73 using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283591/error-system-invalidoperationexception-session-not-created-chrome-version-mus)

Answer (score 2):

**Issue :** Your Chrome Browser Version is 74 and Your framework is having **ChromeDriver Binary v73.0.3683.20** which supports **Chrome Browser v73**

**Solution :** Update your ChromeDriver Binary Version to v74.0.3729.6

Please have a look at **Chrome Browser Release Section :** [Chrome Browser vs ChromeDriver Binary](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and follow below information -

- If you are using *Chrome version 75*, please download [ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/)
- If you are using *Chrome version 74*, please download [ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/) **(You shall follow this)**
- If you are using *Chrome version 73*, please download [ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/)
- For older version of *Chrome*, please see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791) for the version of ChromeDriver that supports it.

Hope following above would resolve your issue.