# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75 using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open the Chrome browser it displays error.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Homepage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Create Driver object
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Workdirectory\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Here I am expecting My Chrome Browser but it throws an error like

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}) on port 21714
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-3JIP3OF', ip: '192.168.1.73', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Comment: The error message is very clear `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75`

Comment: It doesn't work at version 75 downgrade your version to 74.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v75* supports *Chrome Browser v75* only which wasn't available within your system.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=75.0.3770.8*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=75.0.3770.8*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 75**

- The latest released *Chrome* version is *chrome=74.0* which you are currently using.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v75.0* and the *Chrome Browser v74.0*

---

### Solution

- Downgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [ChromeDriver v74.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v74.0*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v74.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt))
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: Thank you @Debanjan it is working on chrome 74 version but my chrome version is 75 Why it is not working for that version.

Comment: @RajasekharBandaru _Chrome v75_ is still in Beta(Dev channel). Possibly we need to make some more tweaks and then GA with a different minor version.

Comment: @DebanjanB this doesn't seem to work in all cases, I tried with the same as well as lower version and still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Error `session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75`. So there is a compatibility issue with the chrome browser version and the chromedriver version. Please get the appropriate chrome driver based on your chrome browser version from the below location.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Hi supputuri,

i downloaded latest version but it shows that error.

Comment: Whats your chrome browser version?