# SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77 using Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using 
ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.10

Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: `2019-06 (4.12.0)`

> Windows 10

I am tried reinstalling my windows to have a fresh OS, but it still didn't help the situation.

Code trials:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class One {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Work\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver Driver=new ChromeDriver();
        Driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.10 (bc3579f611bbc73331171afe020ec7a45e6ccc55-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#93}) on port 32932
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" 
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-P9CFNEOV', ip: '172.20.10.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x0046EBD3+1502163]
Ordinal0 [0x003EF781+980865]
Ordinal0 [0x0037763F+489023]
Ordinal0 [0x0030F2F4+62196]
Ordinal0 [0x0030BCDA+48346]
Ordinal0 [0x003297E0+169952]
Ordinal0 [0x0032940D+168973]
Ordinal0 [0x003278EB+162027]
Ordinal0 [0x00310AC7+68295]
Ordinal0 [0x00311B40+72512]
Ordinal0 [0x00311AD9+72409]
Ordinal0 [0x00408FE7+1085415]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0050D8AD+503293]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0050D640+502672]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0051471C+531564]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0050E0BA+505354]
Ordinal0 [0x004006B6+1050294]
Ordinal0 [0x0040052F+1049903]
Ordinal0 [0x0040B04B+1093707]
Ordinal0 [0x0040B1B3+1094067]
Ordinal0 [0x0040A145+1089861]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75988494+36]
RtlAreBitsSet [0x775641C8+136]
RtlAreBitsSet [0x77564198+88]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at One.main(One.java:10)
```

Comment: looks like chrome driver is not compatible, please use the correct driver for the browser version.

Comment: the error says it "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77"

Answer (score 1):

You should be download and replace this driver to your chrome driver [Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/)

Comment: Replaced the ChromeDriver77 with ChromeDriver76 and now its working good. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.10 (bc3579f611bbc73331171afe020ec7a45e6ccc55-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#93}) on port 32932 
Only local connections are allowed. 
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code. 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 14T08:25:48' 
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-P9CFNEOV', ip: '172.20.10.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_222' 
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=77.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=77.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.10/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 77**

- You are using *chrome= 76.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.12/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v77.0* and the *Chrome Browser v76.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: Thank for taking the time for explaining it in detail. your answer has improved my understanding on the problem better. I Replaced the ChromeDriver77 with ChromeDriver76 and now its working good. Thanks for the help and really appreciate it.

Comment: @YSamKabir Any issues with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need To Download Chrome Driver To this version here is your version link You can click And download: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me. On Mac/Unix based systems.

1. Check your local Chrome version. Then go to:
   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html Download the
   matching major release (minor build version doesn't appear to
   matter) - e.g. 95.local to 95.driver)
2. Extract and click the driver. Apple security won't allow for it to
   be opened. Go to Security, General and Allow.
3. Replace the chromedriver in automation repo/drivers/mac with the new
   driver.
4. Replace the chromedriver in /usr/local/bin (or other system paths >
   can be checked via sudo nano /etc/paths)
5. Ensure you have the matching driver via Terminal > chromedriver
   --version

Now run your test, should work! Came around this thread, but it was trial and error ftw! :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need to download the matching driver version of your Chrome Web Browser version, and make sure JRE version is [image]