# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76 with Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently using Chrome 75 and I've downloaded the [compatible Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.140/) for linux. I've also added it to the PATH variable. However, when I attempt initializing a driver with `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
```

What I get from this message is that my Chromedriver is ment for Chrome version 76, but both my Chromedriver and Chrome browser are version 75.

I even tried deleting the Chromedriver completely from my files and I still get the same error message

Comment: Somewhere else on the PATH you've got another executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your code trials and the error stack trace would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. Though you mentioned about *compatible Chromedriver for linux* but your program while in execution picks up the **ChromeDriver v76.0**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.12/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

---

### Solution

Ensure you have:

- Deleted all the existing different versions of *Chromedriver* from your system.
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current *ChromeDriver v76.0* level.

> Additionally, ensure you pick up the latest release of *ChromeDriver v76.0* i.e. [ChromeDriver v76.0.3809.126](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.126/).

- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: You've been instructed before to reduce the amount over formatting that you use in your answers (see [meta about your posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362515/is-this-formatting-overuse)). You've also been told to avoid promotion of 3rd party tools and excessive explanations.

Comment: @JeffC Until and unless decide to learn the Selenium related new concepts by reading the different answers it will be tough for you to understand how the discussions differs as per their respective usecase.

Comment: Tell me that you aren't using a template with all this text and over formatting in there... [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622223/2386774), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57603953/2386774), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535654/2386774), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57569478/2386774) and those are just from the last few days.

Comment: I found this answer helpful.  Not sure what the fuss is about.

Answer (score 1):

This error implement:

You need to download your version of chrome driver:

You can download your version of chrome driver via clicking here:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.140/