# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey so I have this simple code to open google using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Instead of opening the google page I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
```

Comment: what version of chrome are you using?

Comment: I'm not. Im importing the ```chromedriver_binary``` module which basically gets version 85.0.4183.38 of the web driver and adds it to path without having to add the exe file to path

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v85.0* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You mentioned about using *chromedriver=85.0.4183.38* and the release notes of *chromedriver=85.0.4183.38* clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 85**

- Presumably you are using current version of *Chrome Browser* i.e. **Version 84.0.4147.135**.

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v85.0* and the *Chrome Browser v84.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current (released) *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt)).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome/60300767#60300767)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621700/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea/59624419#59624419)
- [Ubuntu: selenium.common.exceptions: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438332/ubuntu-selenium-common-exceptions-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromed/59454235#59454235)
- [SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77 using Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567812/sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-on/57569478#57569478)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure chrome driver installed match chrome version installed on your machine and path of chrome driver is set to your PATH Variable.
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using this code
`pip install chromedriver-binary==83.0.4103.39`