# Driver info: driver.version: unknown with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It is showing timed out for driver server to start when I use chrome driver. 
And when I try to use Firefox it is showing session unexpectedly exited.
I am trying to run the Remote driver on a server using selenium in python
what should I do?
Unable to create new session.

> UnknownError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
>   Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
>   System info: host: 'server.*******.com', ip: '61.16.155.6', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* wasn't recognized back by the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome* browser.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on version compatibility in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: It was due to normal chrome and firefox driver which I was using. Headless browser helped me with this problem.