# This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 79 error running protractorE2E tests with ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Those are my settings:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node
stages:
    - test
tests:
    stage: test
    before_script:
        # Add Google Chrome to aptitude's (package manager) sources
        - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
        # Fetch Chrome's PGP keys for secure installation
        - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
        # Update aptitude's package sources
        - apt-get -qq update -y
        # Install latest Chrome stable, Xvfb packages
        - apt-get -qq install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base xfonts-scalable imagemagick x11-apps default-jre
        # Launch Xvfb
        - Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
        # Export display for Chrome
        - export DISPLAY=:99
        # Install AngularJS CLI exclusively
        # Add --unsafe-perm to resolve problems with node-gyp infinite loop on Docker
        - npm install --silent --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli@1.1.2
    script:
        - npm i --quiet
        - npm run wd-update
        - npm run wd-start &
        - npm run start -- js-files/psh.conf.js
        - npm run wd-shutdown
    only:
        - master
        - merge_request
```

And this is the job outoput for tests

```
     Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
     on runner-gitlab-runner-554cdd7fbc-4t8mw zxqBkdf4
     Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
     Using Kubernetes executor with image node ...
    Waiting for pod gitlab-managed-apps/runner-zxqbkdf4-project-62-concurrent-15jnmx to be running, status is Pending
    Running on runner-zxqbkdf4-project-62-concurrent-15jnmx via runner-
$ npm i --quiet

> canvas@2.6.0 install /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[canvas] Success: "/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" is installed via remote
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 457 packages from 433 contributors and audited 1390 packages in 15.657s
found 0 vulnerabilities

$ npm run wd-update

> bender@1.0.0 wd-update /builds/automation/bender
> webdriver-manager update

[15:03:41] I/file_manager - creating folder /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[15:03:41] I/config_source - curl -o/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[15:03:41] I/config_source - curl -o/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[15:03:41] I/config_source - curl -o/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
[15:03:42] I/downloader - curl -o/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_78.0.3904.105.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[15:03:42] I/downloader - curl -o/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[15:03:42] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_78.0.3904.105.zip
[15:03:42] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_78.0.3904.105
[15:03:42] I/downloader - curl -o/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0.tar.gz https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
[15:03:43] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.26.0.tar.gz
[15:03:43] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0
$ npm run wd-start &
$ npm run start -- js-files/psh.conf.js

> bender@1.0.0 wd-start /builds/automation/bender
> webdriver-manager start


> bender@1.0.0 prestart /builds/automation/bender
> tsc && ts-cleaner -d js-files

[15:03:44] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_78.0.3904.105 -jar /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[15:03:44] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 15684
15:03:45.253 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
15:03:45.506 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-12-17 15:03:45.713:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1029ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
15:03:46.441 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
15:03:46.780 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444

> bender@1.0.0 start /builds/automation/bender
> node src/flake "js-files/psh.conf.js"

[15:03:52] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:03:52] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
15:03:52.446 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--headless",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--window-size=1550,768"
    ]
  },
  "count": 1,
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "shardTestFiles": false
}
15:03:52.449 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 3722
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1576595032.499][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
[1576595033.109][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 79.
15:03:53.266 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
15:03:53.323 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 26b7b655c1318cbcde9cfb69871f56ad (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
(node:15719) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Started
Jasmine started
2019-12-17T15:03:53.447Z - info: Current test running: 
    Psh site validations Site language should change

(node:15719) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'runner-zxqbkdf4-project-62-concurrent-15jnmx', ip: '10.36.0.39', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.138+', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15719) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15719) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:15719) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'runner-zxqbkdf4-project-62-concurrent-15jnmx', ip: '10.36.0.39', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.138+', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15719) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:15719) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'runner-zxqbkdf4-project-62-concurrent-15jnmx', ip: '10.36.0.39', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.138+', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at /builds/automation/bender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15719) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

So, the error that I having is:
**`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: invalid session id`**

- **Any idea about this?**

I was researching about two days at least and I didn't found anything related, I see a lot of errors but no one like this.

- **Should I use a docker image? instead install everything on the fly?**

I couldn't find a docker image that match with my necessity.

- **Is the seleniumaddress that I'm using correct?**

It's the one recommended by protractor site:  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70
.
[1576595033.109][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 79.
.
15:03:53.323 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 26b7b655c1318cbcde9cfb69871f56ad (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
(node:15719) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=78.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=78.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 78**

- You are using *chrome= 79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v78.0* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: Definitively makes sense to me, let me try that. Thank you.

Comment: Marked as correct, since that was my blocker to get running my tests in pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using npm implementation of protractor type below command in cmd . Today by chrome version was changed to 79 and doing this solved my issue .

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: Yup, you're right.

This was my output.
`[20:44:40] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.zip`

Comment: Thanks, I've running my tests in pipeline :tada: