# Does Chromedriver 79.0.3945.88. exist?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, continuous-integration, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

I'm running my Selenium CI tests on a remote Jenkins Linux machine. I'm also using WebDriverManager to manage the Chromedriver.

The remote Chrome version is 79.0.3945.88. This is something **I don't have permission to change**.
When Chrome version got updated from 78 I started getting warnings

```
07:26:19 [1579242379.444][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 79.
```

So I updated the Chromedriver

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("79.0.3945.88").setup();
```

but then I would get

```
09:02:35 09:02:35.908 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - The proper chromedriver version for your Google Chrome is unknown ... trying with the latest
09:02:37 09:02:36.999 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Latest version of chromedriver according to https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE is 79.0.3945.36
09:02:37 09:02:37.030 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/79.0.3945.36/chromedriver
```

And the test would still fail, because the HTML of the page wouldn't load. I tried extending wait times, but this didn't help.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378782/this-version-of-chromedriver-has-not-been-tested-with-chrome-version-79-error-ru) the next thing I tried all of the Chromedriver 78 and 79 versions found at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads but none worked.

After that, I tried to find a precise `.88` version and used this

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().targetPath("https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/chromedriver-79.0.3945.88-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html").version("79.0.3904.88").setup();

but the result was:

```
13:33:47 13:33:47.404 [main] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek chromedriver
13:33:48 13:33:48.566 [main] ERROR i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - chromedriver 79.0.3904.88 for LINUX64 not found in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
13:33:48 13:33:48.568 [main] WARN  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing chromedriver 79.0.3904.88 (chromedriver 79.0.3904.88 for LINUX64 not found in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/) ... trying again using mirror
13:34:59 13:34:59.973 [main] ERROR i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - chromedriver 79.0.3904.88 for LINUX64 not found in http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/
13:34:59 13:34:59.973 [main] WARN  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing chromedriver 79.0.3904.88 (chromedriver 79.0.3904.88 for LINUX64 not found in http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/) ... trying again using latest from cache
13:35:03 13:35:03.454 [main] DEBUG i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Latest version of chromedriver according to http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/LATEST_RELEASE is 79.0.3945.36
13:35:53 13:35:53.530 [main] INFO  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Downloading http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/79.0.3945.36/chromedriver_linux64.zip
13:35:54 13:35:54.771 [main] INFO  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Extracting binary from compressed file chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

I've also updated WebDriverManager from 3.2.0 to 3.7.0 and finally to 3.8.1 but nothing helped.

Is there a way for me to load a precise `79.0.3945.88.` version of Chromedriver?

Or is there another workaround?

Comment: There is no version 79.0.3945.88, you should use version 79.0.3945.36. Did you download it?

Comment: Web Driver Manager takes care of it. It defaulted to .36 when .88 was not found. But it didn't help.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: There was no warnings from web driver manager, but the tests still failed because the HTML elements were not found on the page.

Comment: This could be a simple matter of timing issue, do you use waits?

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned in OP, I tried different wait times (up to a minute), but no use.

Comment: Is the browser maximized on the remote machine? if the jenkins slave runs as a service the browser will be smaller, which might effect the tests. Even as a regular process it might run in a smaller mode.

Comment: It is maximized. I get the screenshots on failure that is why I know the HTML is not loaded properly. I can see the header and footer elements, but not the table elements. As I said, it is not a timing issue, I suspect chromedriver is not loading the elements properly.

Comment: Chromedriver doesn't load the elements, it's just a connection to the browser. If you navigate to the site manually on this browser version is it loading properly? you could also try to refresh the page with the driver, it's a horrible workaround but it might indicate if it's really a loading problem.

Answer (score 2):

All chromedriver versions could be found:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
so latest for 79 at this moment is 79.0.3945.36 .
You could probably use it or even newer such as 80.0.3987.16 .

I personally use tool selenium-standalone which makes this task just work.
Of course You could also download driver manually and use it. But just start with simplest example of driver that will work.

Comment: With any combination of chrome/chromedriver 79 I just get a blank page.

Comment: What browser init are You using ???? And what selenium version are U using ???

Comment: 79.0.3945.88., as the original post states.

Answer (score 0):

***Resolved! steps:***

1.) Download chrome webdriver (check your installed chrome version and download the relevant driver) form: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

2.) Add these lines:

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

3.) Remove or comment following: (if present in your code)

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();