# InvalidOperationException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76 with ChromeDriver Selenium in AzureDevOPS

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have Ux Automation test project where in I am using the NuGet for Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver. The Agent in the release pipeline has below versions of chrome & WebDriver

```
Google Chrome
version:
75.0.3770.100

Selenium Web Drivers
Chrome Driver
version:
75.0.3770.90
Environment:
ChromeWebDriver: location of chromedriver.exe
```

I have tried check-in the project with 75 & 76 NuGet reference. However, I am getting below error in both cases.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76 (SessionNotCreated)
```

Which version it is complaining for?

Comment: It looks like your Google Chrome is version 75, but the ChromeDriver supports Google Chrome 76, not 75.

Comment: Even if I use ChromeDriver 75 it is giving the same error

Comment: Have you tried using Google Chrome 76 and Chromedriver 75?

Comment: The document says it is 75 and the actual agent was with 78. So it seems they have not updated their document :(

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76 (SessionNotCreated)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you mentioned about using *chromedriver=75.0.3770.90* there may be multiple instances of **chromedriver** being present in your system and the the version of the *chromedriver* which is effective in your tests is ***chromedriver=76.0***
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

- Presumably you are using *chrome= 75.0*.
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome 75**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v76.0* and the *Chrome Browser v75.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)