# how selenium can identify if there is a browser upgraded?

Tags: selenium

Since browser auto-update runs on the system unless we manually turn it off,
how to automate in selenium to identify if there is a browser upgraded?

Comment: try to show some effort in what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If the browser updates e.g. Chrome, you will need to have the compatible binary for that browser. There's a good answer and overview on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up).

To avoid this, I personally used ephemeral instances of Chrome, specifically [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) and containerized tests using [docker-selenium](https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium).