# Running headless Chrome / Puppeteer with --no-sandbox

Tags: docker, chromium, puppeteer

**Background**

I built an application that uses Puppeteer on my localhost. Now that I am trying to deploy it into a debian environment the script that runs Puppeteer is timing out. After researching it I realized it is a common problem. Most debian environments are missing the dependencies needed to run Chromium.

**Problem**

[I found some recommended ways to run the application using Docker here.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md)

I can run the application using Docker, but once I add the Chrome specific data to my Docker file I am getting a few errors.

> Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network
>   namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted

It is suggested to run the app as a user made in the Docker file. But, when I add that user, the user gets the error mentioned above.

Then when I try and run the application as root, I get a new error,

> Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.

Although it is not recommended, I want to get the app running even with `--no-sandbox` to see if it works.

**Example**

I have been running the application like this,

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 user/app-name
```

***Docker File***

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Application parameters and variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=3000
ENV Root_Dir /
ENV application_directory /usr/src/app
ENV font_directory /usr/share/fonts/noto

# Configuration for Chrome
ENV CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=60000
ENV CHROME_PATH=/usr/bin/google-chrome

RUN mkdir -p $application_directory
RUN mkdir -p $font_directory

# Dependencies needed for packages downstream
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  apt-utils \
  unzip \
  fontconfig \
  locales \
  gconf-service \
  libasound2 \
  libatk1.0-0 \
  libc6 \
  libcairo2 \
  libcups2 \
  libdbus-1-3 \
  libexpat1 \
  libfontconfig1 \
  libgcc1 \
  libgconf-2-4 \
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
  libglib2.0-0 \
  libgtk-3-0 \
  libnspr4 \
  libpango-1.0-0 \
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
  libstdc++6 \
  libx11-6 \
  libx11-xcb1 \
  libxcb1 \
  libxcomposite1 \
  libxcursor1 \
  libxdamage1 \
  libxext6 \
  libxfixes3 \
  libxi6 \
  libxrandr2 \
  libxrender1 \
  libxss1 \
  libxtst6 \
  ca-certificates \
  fonts-liberation \
  libappindicator1 \
  libnss3 \
  lsb-release \
  xdg-utils \
  wget

# It's a good idea to use dumb-init to help prevent zombie chrome processes.
ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

# Install Node.js
RUN apt-get install --yes curl &&\
  curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - &&\
  apt-get install --yes nodejs &&\
  apt-get install --yes build-essential

# Install emoji's
RUN cd $font_directory &&\
  wget https://github.com/emojione/emojione-assets/releases/download/3.1.2/emojione-android.ttf &&\
  wget https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-cjk/blob/master/NotoSansCJKsc-Medium.otf?raw=true && \
  fc-cache -f -v

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
        --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer

# Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
   && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
   && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
   && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /node_modules

RUN cd $application_directory

WORKDIR $application_directory

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build
RUN npm install

USER pptruser

# Expose the web-socket and HTTP ports
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["google-chrome-unstable", "npm", "start"]
```

**Question**

How do I run Docker and pass the ,

```
--no-sandbox
```

param so it will let me run this in root?

Or, what do I need to change in my current Docker file so it will let me run it as the `USER pptruser`

Current Problems -

Runnning as

```
USER pptruser
```

> Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network
>   namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted

Running as

```
root
```

> Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.

Comment: Did you try to [enable the sandbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox) using `sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` ?

Comment: This isnt an option for Alpine users. any work around? @SkippyleGrandGourou

Comment: @Oxycash Sorry, I don't know Alpine and haven't played with Puppeteer for 2 years.  Also, I don't understand why I commented here, my comment seems completely off topic since OP specifically mentioned they wanted to run without the sandbox, even in the question title…

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I was hitting a similar problem trying to run Chromium headless in an Alpine Docker container, and apparently so are many other (e.g., [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/496), [here](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/65)). The `--no-sandbox` option is a straightforward workaround but obviously a poor security practice. What worked for me was setting a custom [`seccomp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/).

Download [this file](https://github.com/jessfraz/dotfiles/blob/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json) (if interested, see the author's notes [here](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/how-to-use-new-docker-seccomp-profiles/)). Then pass the option `--security-opt seccomp=path/to/chrome.json` when starting Docker, or specify the same option in your `docker-compose.yml` if you're using one.

Comment: Anyone figured out the specific config option for docker-compose?

Comment: For docker-compose, see the example [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5574). Just note that the relative path is relative not to the yaml, but to your working directory.

Comment: This solution is now 6 years old. Has anyone found a "better" alternative ?

Comment: How do you run this in google cloud run, given that you aren't running `docker run`?

Answer (score 22):

In your nodejs code when you launch your browser, you can pass the  `--no-sandbox` argument.

example:-

```
const launchBrowser = async () => {
  puppetBrowser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    timeout: 10000,
  });
};
```

Comment: This is a giant security hole.

Comment: @IsaiahNorton Could you tell me (us) if that's also the case in a Docker container, run as a non-root user?

Comment: A malicious site could potentially take over the docker container. It's not the end of the world, but the attacker would have access to any code and data inside the docker container.

Comment: @IsaiahNorton Why is it a security hole? What is you alternative solution? Do you have a better idea or a different parameter to increase security?

Comment: @IsaiahNorton is this because the puppet is accessing the internet and could be compromised that way?

Comment: For reference, asked about the security implications of `--no-sandbox` here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/274583/how-does-a-hacker-get-access-to-the-root-user-when-disabling-the-sandbox-in-pupp

Answer (score 8):

**Background**

I was the OP. Months have went by and I continue to see people having similar problems all over the internet. Github issues and SO. Due to that I want to show everyone how I solved this issue.

**Problem**

Running Puppeteer on Debian fails due to missing libs.

**Solution**

I was able to run the application using a Docker file and adding a config option to Puppeteer.

**Examples**

***Docker File***

```
FROM node:8
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apt-get update

# for https
RUN apt-get install -yyq ca-certificates
# install libraries
RUN apt-get install -yyq libappindicator1 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
# tools
RUN apt-get install -yyq gconf-service lsb-release wget xdg-utils
# and fonts
RUN apt-get install -yyq fonts-liberation

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/views

# install the necessary packages
RUN npm install

CMD npm run start
```

***Puppeteer***

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
          ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
          dumpio: false
        });
```

I hope this helps. Basically when running the app you will install the missing libs by configuring your Docker file then when your app is running the config options passed to the Puppeteer object will allow your app to run on Debian.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need of a timeout,

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args:['--no-sandbox']});`

Comment: Well i wasn't using  puppeteer library directly,this made my task difficult to implement this but somehow your answer helped me figure out the problem with the library node-html-to-image  and i fixed it.