# Puppeteer --no-sandbox security risk

Tags: puppeteer

I've read ([Running headless Chrome / Puppeteer with --no-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662388/running-headless-chrome-puppeteer-with-no-sandbox)) that --no-sandbox has security risks, but why? I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and node.js. I don't know what the setting does, so can someone explain.

I've read the short snippet from here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md, but I still don't know what this sandbox is for. A page on the headless browser can't have security problems unless it finds a loophole and downloads files right?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68832/what-does-the-chromium-option-no-sandbox-mean

Comment: I have the same question. I've searched the internet about this and understand that "--no-sandbox" is less secure and makes Chrome more vulnerable. But it would be nice to see a specific example how a web-page can attack my computer when running Chrome with "--no-sandbox".