# why is "--no-sandbox" a unsafe arg in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I've been having some issues to run puppeteer (and pyppeteer) in cloud. I found this "trick" as a solution, which works nice actually. but i've also seen people talking that is [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662388/running-headless-chrome-puppeteer-with-no-sandbox), and I can't really get why, mostly because I don't really understand what it does.

here goes some example:

```js
const launchBrowser = async () => {
  puppetBrowser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
};
```

Comment: _I've been having some issues to run puppeteer _ -- for completeness, you might want to briefly list what these issues are. You may [not actually need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) a sandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very useful answer on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68951) why sandboxes should be used. Overall the process sandbox just puts the process in some kind of jail on the OS and protects it more from other processes.

> I was not sure I could post it as an answer as I did not specifically address *"where vulnerability comes from"* - and mere refs then own words. But anyhow –
>
> Hopefully this shed some light on the topic of *sandbox*:
>
> - [Quick introduction](http://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/med_26.html) to Chrome's sandbox.
> - More in depth [design document](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md). With internal links to FAQ, etc.
>
> And as stated, Google themselves recommend using another browser than using Chrome without sandbox. And then obviously understood as if one can fix it then that would be preferred ;)

(i updated the link here to the new source of the design document)

However, the sandbox feature may cause some trouble too. I for myself have trouble if i launch a chromium based application from a mounted NTFS partition in a directory (`C:\somedir = \\hardisk2\partition1`). Where turning it off, solves all challenges.

There are [a lot of threads](https://www.google.com/search?q=steam+no+cef+sandbox) out there, where Steam for example "requires" the `-no-cef-sandbox` flag to display the web-content in several situations.

The cross origin-blocks or iframe-sandbox has nothing todo with the `-no-sandbox` flag. The cross origin blocks, are still active, even if you start the browser without the process sandbox. As you can see in this snippet. Just start a new session with `-no-sandbox` to proof it. Also keep in mind, that there is not even a sandbox flag on the iframe. (for example: `chromium -incognito -no-sandbox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66998228/why-is-no-sandbox-a-unsafe-arg-in-puppeteer`)

```js
window.accessChild = function(event) {
  try {
    this.contentWindow.document
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4R-587BCu9k" onload="accessChild.call(this, event)"></iframe>
```

And you will get an alert with a cross origin access block.